# What is the best practice of updating entities in Linq2SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql

Just wanted to understand what is the best practice of updating entities using linq2sql?

A bit more details to undestand the question better.

As I understood from the articles, I can have 2 situations: entity is attached to the context and entity constructed from the scratch(or from existing entity). I wanted to have only one method to update entites, that's implemented in the following way for now:

```
 public virtual void Save<T>(T value) where T : class
 {
      Context.GetTable<T>().Attach(value);
      Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, value);
      Context.SubmitChanges();
 }
```

Of course, when I execute the code:

```
var orders = GenericRepository.Instance.Find<BuyerOrder>(b => b.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
orders.Price = 397809;
GenericRepository.Instance.Save(orders);
```

the object is already attached to the context and I got an exception:

```
Cannot attach an entity that already exists.
```

Should I always detach objects before saving? Is there another way to overcome this issue?

Sorry if the question is dumb - this is my first experiences with linq2sql

Answer (score 1):

In your `Save` method, don't Attach the table. It also doesn't need to take a type, you can just call `Context.SubmitChanges` inside your Save method. Something like:

```
public void Save()
{
    Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Then do:

```
var orders = GenericRepository.Instance.Find<BuyerOrder>(b => b.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
orders.Price = 397809;
GenericRepository.Instance.Save();
```

See MSDN for some more examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx

Comment: This is the correct answer. Never detach your entity and don't play tricks. Don't "save" individual entities. Make changes to your object graph as a whole and call SaveChanges at the end.

Comment: thank you for the answer. But how can I define that the entity is attached to the context? I want to handle 2 situation in 1 method: when the entity is attached to the context and when it is not

Comment: You can define whether an entity is attached by using the answer outlined in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493737/how-do-i-check-whether-a-linq-to-sql-object-is-already-attached-to-a-datacontext

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the entity is attached like this:

```
if (!Context.GetTable<T>().IsAttached(value))
{
    Context.GetTable<T>().Attach(value);
}
Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, value);
Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I misunderstood smth. I don't see Context's method IsAttched.